# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port

Tags: selenium-webdriver, error-handling

```
    package Demo_Test;


    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

     public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\d-syeed.farrakhan\\Downloads\\chrome-win32\\chrome-win32\\chrome.exe");  
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();  
        
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            driver.close();
        
            System.out.println("We finished.");
         }
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:541)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:52)
at Demo_Test.First.main(First.java:15)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port.
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
... 7 more
Here is the code and the error.

Comment: you've set the path to the driver to chrome.exe (that's the browser).